# Close browser after pop-up appears

Tags: javascript, php

After user has logged in, a popup window appears displaying the index.php. However the original browser that had the login.php changes to authenticate.php. **How do i close the previous browser entirely?**

```html
<?php 
session_start();
require_once './config/config.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
    $passwd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'passwd');
    $remember = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'remember');
    $passwd=  md5($passwd);
    
    //Get DB instance. function is defined in config.php
    $db = getDbInstance();

    $db->where ("user_name", $username);
    $db->where ("passwd", $passwd);
    $row = $db->get('admin_accounts');
     
    if ($db->count >= 1) {
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['admin_type'] = htmlentities ($row[0]['admin_type']);
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = htmlentities ($row[0]['first_name']);
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = htmlentities ($row[0]['last_name']);
        $_SESSION['position'] = htmlentities ($row[0]['position']);
        if($remember)
        {
         setcookie('username',$username , time() + (86400 * 90), "/");
         setcookie('password',$passwd , time() + (86400 * 90), "/");
        }
        echo "<script>window.open('http://localhost/index', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');</script>";
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['login_failure'] = "Invalid username or password";
        header('Location:login');
        exit;
    }
  
}
```

This is the bit of the code that opens the popup window:

```html
echo "<script>window.open('http://localhost/index', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');</script>";
```

I have already tried using window.close();

```html
echo "<script>window.close(); window.open('http://localhost/index', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');</script>";
```

Comment: This seems like strange and non user friendly behavior. Why do you open new window in the first place instead of loading index in original tab(window)?

Comment: The user friendliness of this isn't the main concern. I'm just interested in this.

Comment: Basic rule is you can only close a window that was opened by script originally and you still have stored reference to that window that is returned from `window.open()`

Comment: Is there a way to open a popup from a chrome short cut link? (I have created a short cut on my desktop that goes to http://localhost/index is it possible to open this as a popup window?

Comment: I don't see why you can't just use `AJAX` to post the login details to a `php` file and use the `ajax` events to deal with the response rather than having `php` echo javascript. It could make the source code much cleaner and easier to work with.

Comment: Not 100% sure...don't think so. Keep in mind there are lots of security issues that are protected by browsers to prevent abuse & malicious stuff in links. Might try right click on that desktop link though

Comment: @NewToJS how would your ajax suggestion look like? Im not 100% familiar with ajax. Could you edit my code please. I'd love to learn

Comment: Do some research on `AJAX` You will find many examples for you to work with. I am not doing all the work for you because you will not learn from that. Sometimes to learn something new you need to take the time and have the patience to learn it.

Comment: And ajax tutorials are abundant all over the place